# How CBOR Parse Task in Standard mode works?

Tags: chainlink, cbor

I wonder how `cborparse` in `mode="standard"` works cause I can't make it work.

### Resources

[Chainlink CBOR Parse Task - docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/jobs/task-types/cborparse/)

[Chainlink CBOR Prase Task - implementation](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/core/services/pipeline/task.cborparse.go)

[Chainlink CBOR Parse Task - implementation tests](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/core/services/pipeline/task.cborparse_test.go)

[Online CBOR encoder](https://cbor.me/)
[Online uft8 to bytes converter](https://onlineutf8tools.com/convert-utf8-to-bytes)

### Environment

Chainlink Node v1.7.0, and v1.8.1.

### Case OK: cborparse in mode="diet" (default)

#### Test Case

**Input**

```json
{"path":["recent","usd"],"url":"https://etherprice.com/api"}
```

**Input CBOR encoded**

```
A264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069
```

**Webhook TOML spec**

```ini
type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Test decode CBOR diet"
observationSource = """
    merge               [type="merge" left=<{"input": "0x"}> right=<{"input": "0xA264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069"}>]
    decode_cbor         [type="cborparse" data="$(merge.input)"]

    merge -> decode_cbor
"""
```

**JSON job run**

```json
{
  "__typename": "JobRun",
  "id": "240",
  "allErrors": [
  ],
  "createdAt": "2022-10-14T12:06:56.646544Z",
  "fatalErrors": [
  ],
  "finishedAt": "2022-10-14T12:06:56.64718Z",
  "job": {
    "__typename": "Job",
    "id": "225",
    "name": "Test decode CBOR diet",
    "observationSource": " merge [type="merge" left=<{"input": "0x"}> right=<{"input": "0xA264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069"}>] decode_cbor [type="cborparse" data="$(merge.input)"] "
  },
  "status": "COMPLETED",
  "inputs": {
    "decode_cbor": {
      "path": [
        "recent",
        "usd"
      ],
      "url": "https://etherprice.com/api"
    },
    "jobRun": {
      "meta": null
    },
    "merge": {
      "input": "0xA264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069"
    }
  },
  "outputs": [
    "{"path":["recent","usd"],"url":"https://etherprice.com/api"}"
  ],
  "taskRuns": [
  ]
}
```

### Case KO: cborparse in mode="standard"

#### Test Case

**Input**

```json
{"path":["recent","usd"],"url":"https://etherprice.com/api"}
```

**Input CBOR encoded**

```
A264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069
```

**Input CBOR encoded as array of bytes**

```
[41, 32, 36, 34, 37, 30, 36, 31, 37, 34, 36, 38, 38, 32, 36, 36, 37, 32, 36, 35, 36, 33, 36, 35, 36, 45, 37, 34, 36, 33, 37, 35, 37, 33, 36, 34, 36, 33, 37, 35, 37, 32, 36, 43, 37, 38, 31, 41, 36, 38, 37, 34, 37, 34, 37, 30, 37, 33, 33, 41, 32, 46, 32, 46, 36, 35, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 35, 37, 32, 37, 30, 37, 32, 36, 39, 36, 33, 36, 35, 32, 45, 36, 33, 36, 46, 36, 44, 32, 46, 36, 31, 37, 30, 36, 39]
```

Below few TOML specs attempted but none of them work. They always fail with `data: parameter is empty` (common part of the JSON job run shared below):

```json
{
  "__typename": "JobRun",
  "id": "246",
  "allErrors": [
    "data: parameter is empty"
  ],
  "createdAt": "2022-10-14T12:31:42.234027Z",
  "fatalErrors": [
    "data: parameter is empty"
  ],
  "finishedAt": "2022-10-14T12:31:42.236091Z",
  "job": {
    "__typename": "Job",
    "id": "232",
    "name": "Test decode CBOR standard",
    "observationSource": " decode_cbor [type="cborparse" mode="standard" data=<it_does_not_matter>] "
  },
  "status": "ERRORED",
  "inputs": {
    "decode_cbor": {
    },
    "jobRun": {
      "meta": null
    }
  },
  "outputs": [
    null
  ],
  "taskRuns": [
    {
      "__typename": "TaskRun",
      "id": "9c374ffb-cf80-41c9-a3b7-08391abd48fa",
      "createdAt": "2022-10-14T12:31:42.234993Z",
      "dotID": "decode_cbor",
      "error": "data: parameter is empty",
      "finishedAt": "2022-10-14T12:31:42.236021Z",
      "output": "null",
      "type": "cborparse"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Test 1: webhook TOML spec where data has an hexStr**

`data` has is a hexStr

```ini
type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Test decode CBOR diet 1"
observationSource = """
    decode_cbor         [type="cborparse" mode="standard" data="0xA264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069"]
"""
```

I've tried also multiple syntax combinations, adding and removing `[ ]`, `0x`, `""`. For instance:

```ini
type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Test decode CBOR standard 3"
observationSource = """
    decode_cbor         [type="cborparse" mode="standard" data=<{["0xA264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069"]}>]
"""
```

**Test 2: webhook TOML spec where data does not have hexStr**

`data` is `<{ ... }>`. I've also tried this with scaped quotes (old syntax)

```ini
type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Test decode CBOR standard 1"
observationSource = """
    decode_cbor         [type="cborparse" mode="standard" data=<{41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 34, 36, 33, 36, 31, 36, 43, 36, 43, 36, 36, 36, 39, 36, 45, 37, 30, 37, 35, 37, 34, 37, 33, 38, 32, 41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 39, 37, 32, 36, 35, 37, 31, 37, 35, 36, 35, 37, 33, 37, 34, 34, 39, 36, 34, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 37, 36, 32, 37, 39, 37, 34, 36, 35, 37, 33, 33, 33, 33, 32, 41, 34, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 37, 37, 32, 36, 35, 37, 33, 37, 35, 36, 43, 37, 34, 37, 33, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 37, 36, 32, 37, 39, 37, 34, 36, 35, 37, 33, 35, 42, 35, 44, 36, 36, 36, 35, 36, 45, 36, 33, 36, 46, 36, 34, 36, 35, 41, 32, 36, 36, 36, 44, 36, 35, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 34, 36, 36, 37, 30, 36, 31, 36, 33, 36, 42, 36, 35, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 31, 37, 34, 36, 31, 36, 41, 37, 32, 36, 35, 37, 33, 37, 35, 36, 43, 37, 34, 37, 33, 35, 32, 36, 31, 37, 37, 36, 41, 36, 33, 36, 46, 36, 44, 37, 30, 36, 46, 36, 45, 36, 35, 36, 45, 37, 34, 37, 33, 38, 35, 41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 36, 36, 37, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 34, 39, 36, 34, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 36, 37, 35, 36, 39, 36, 45, 37, 34, 33, 33, 33, 32, 41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 39, 37, 33, 37, 34, 36, 31, 37, 32, 37, 34, 35, 34, 36, 39, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 36, 37, 35, 36, 39, 36, 45, 37, 34, 33, 34, 33, 30, 41, 34, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 45, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 44, 36, 35, 35, 34, 36, 35, 36, 31, 36, 44, 34, 43, 36, 35, 36, 45, 36, 37, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 35, 37, 35, 36, 39, 36, 45, 37, 34, 33, 38, 36, 36, 36, 44, 36, 35, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 34, 36, 36, 36, 43, 36, 35, 36, 45, 36, 37, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 31, 37, 34, 36, 31, 36, 38, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 44, 36, 35, 35, 34, 36, 35, 36, 31, 36, 44, 41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 38, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 44, 36, 35, 35, 34, 36, 35, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 36, 37, 33, 37, 34, 37, 32, 36, 39, 36}>]
"""
```

`data` is `<{[ ... ]}>`. I've also tried this with scaped quotes (old syntax)

```ini
type = "webhook"
schemaVersion = 1
name = "Test decode CBOR standard 2"
observationSource = """
    decode_cbor         [type="cborparse" mode="standard" data=<{[41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 34, 36, 33, 36, 31, 36, 43, 36, 43, 36, 36, 36, 39, 36, 45, 37, 30, 37, 35, 37, 34, 37, 33, 38, 32, 41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 39, 37, 32, 36, 35, 37, 31, 37, 35, 36, 35, 37, 33, 37, 34, 34, 39, 36, 34, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 37, 36, 32, 37, 39, 37, 34, 36, 35, 37, 33, 33, 33, 33, 32, 41, 34, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 37, 37, 32, 36, 35, 37, 33, 37, 35, 36, 43, 37, 34, 37, 33, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 37, 36, 32, 37, 39, 37, 34, 36, 35, 37, 33, 35, 42, 35, 44, 36, 36, 36, 35, 36, 45, 36, 33, 36, 46, 36, 34, 36, 35, 41, 32, 36, 36, 36, 44, 36, 35, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 34, 36, 36, 37, 30, 36, 31, 36, 33, 36, 42, 36, 35, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 31, 37, 34, 36, 31, 36, 41, 37, 32, 36, 35, 37, 33, 37, 35, 36, 43, 37, 34, 37, 33, 35, 32, 36, 31, 37, 37, 36, 41, 36, 33, 36, 46, 36, 44, 37, 30, 36, 46, 36, 45, 36, 35, 36, 45, 37, 34, 37, 33, 38, 35, 41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 36, 36, 37, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 34, 39, 36, 34, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 36, 37, 35, 36, 39, 36, 45, 37, 34, 33, 33, 33, 32, 41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 39, 37, 33, 37, 34, 36, 31, 37, 32, 37, 34, 35, 34, 36, 39, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 36, 37, 35, 36, 39, 36, 45, 37, 34, 33, 34, 33, 30, 41, 34, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 45, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 44, 36, 35, 35, 34, 36, 35, 36, 31, 36, 44, 34, 43, 36, 35, 36, 45, 36, 37, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 35, 37, 35, 36, 39, 36, 45, 37, 34, 33, 38, 36, 36, 36, 44, 36, 35, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 34, 36, 36, 36, 43, 36, 35, 36, 45, 36, 37, 37, 34, 36, 38, 36, 34, 36, 34, 36, 31, 37, 34, 36, 31, 36, 38, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 44, 36, 35, 35, 34, 36, 35, 36, 31, 36, 44, 41, 32, 36, 34, 36, 45, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 35, 36, 38, 36, 38, 36, 46, 36, 44, 36, 35, 35, 34, 36, 35, 36, 31, 36, 44, 36, 34, 37, 34, 37, 39, 37, 30, 36, 35, 36, 36, 37, 33, 37, 34, 37, 32, 36, 39, 36]}>]
""
```

### Summary

Did I get wrong how this task is used and its purpose?
May be the `standard` mode [just return straight data?](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/5a830b237cd187eaf9bb5735d8610835520a82c3/core/cbor/cbor.go#L41), but why I'm always getting `data parameters is empty`?

One alternative for me to understand better what's going on would be implementing a unit test in `task.cborparse_test.go`, but may be someone has the answer!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using mode=standard, can actually skip the character `<{[`.

So you can specify the value of `data` in the TOML as the hex string

`decode_cbor  [type="cborparse" mode="standard" data="0xA264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069"]`

***or***

reference it from a variable like `$(foo)`.

Give that a shot and let me know if you've had trouble.

Also, not sure you need the merge task :

`merge [ type="merge" left=<{"input": "0x"}> right=<{"input": "0xA264706174688266726563656E74637573646375726C781A68747470733A2F2F657468657270726963652E636F6D2F617069"}>]`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your TOML was my first attemp but it does not work. Sorry if this post is not clear, but this is why I've used more "exotic" combinations of `data`. I'll edit the post including your TOML as an example of job that does not work either.

The merge task is just a quick way of having in a `$(merge.input)` variable the value I want on a 2 tasks webhook.

Thanks!

Comment: I've already updated the post explicitely including the TOML as the first example. Also worth mentioning that I've updated my node to v1.8.1 and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: Someone I know was able to achieve it with the TOML i pasted into the response.  There must be something else that is going on -- also i think your KO example, updated TOML v1 refers to diet mode 1 (in the name property) but is meant to be standard right? Could it be another similar typo/error elsewhere?

Comment: Thanks again for answering. I tried you example again right after you posted it and it failed, and I've tried it again now on a v1.9.0. The error is the same: `data: parameter is empty`.  The name on the JSON job definitely is misleading, it comes from a `standard` JSON job run. I don't think there is a typo/error anywhere else tbh, it is a one line observationSource job.